# Changing every number with a percentage sign

Tags: vba, excel

so my first problem got solved but I am have another with my code.

I want to find every number with percentage sign and show it as number with four decimals. 
The code should work even when the number is formated as standard or text or if its writen like "2.89%" or this "2,89%"

```
   Sub test()

Dim bereich As Range, Cell As Range

Set bereich = Range("J1:J100")

For Each Cell In bereich
   If Cell.NumberFormat = "0%" Then Cell.NumberFormat = "0.0000%"
Next Cell

End Sub
```

This is my old code an it works just with number in this "0%" but  I need this code more flexible to the input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `InStr(Cell.Value2, "%") > 0`.

**Modifed Code**

```
For Each Cell In bereich
   If Cell.NumberFormat = "0%" Or InStr(Cell.Value2, "%") > 0 Then Cell.NumberFormat = "0.0000%"
Next Cell
```

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, it doesnt work. Lets say my cells can be filled with this 2.56%
45,00000%
3,45%
5%
and after using the code I want to have it shown like this:2,5600%
45,0000%
3,4500%
5,0000%

Comment: Try using `Cell.Text` instead of `Cell.Value2`

Comment: with cell.text its working! Just one issue: I use US data with a point before the decimals as well as european with a coma. The Us data dont get formated with the code. The output should be number with a coma.

Comment: When I use a serch and replace makro before your come to replace all points with a coma. The number also dont get formated an there is like a little warining sign saying: "The number in this cell is formated as text"